# Restoring the Outlook "you have mail" icon

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, taskbar, icons, restore

So I'm running Outlook at work; I've done SOMETHING (but I don't know what) that stopped the little envelope icon from appearing in the system taskbar when I have new mail.  I actually find that indicator rather useful; how can I get it back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can go to **Tools --> Options**.

Then click on **E-mail Options**.

Then click on **Advanced E-mail Options**.

**Check the box** that says Show an envelope icon in the notification area

Answer (score 8):

Is it possible it's just hidden?

On XP, right-click the taskbar, go to properties, and click "Customize..." in the Notification area group. Find the "You have new unopened items." item and change it to "Always show". I assume the process is similar on other versions of Windows.

If this doesn't do it, check your settings in Outlook (see quicksel's answer).

Answer (score 1):

if its not hidden (as already mentioned) you can find the setting for it in the settings/preferences